# possibilities to combine two Android App's

Tags: java, eclipse, android

I would like to know what's the best possibility to combine two Android Apps together?

I am working on a Loginpage for my Project.
My friend is working on a Dataviewpage for the same Project.

I would like to know what are our options to combine these two Apps (both just in local eclipse), when we finished the seperate project's.

Our current Idea, would be to copy one part in the Eclipse and build it into the other one.

I am aware of, that this is the worst idea but I have no idea to do it an other way.

Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a project as library and use it across ur applications.

Comment: Use SVN (Subversion) or Git for centralize your app. Have a checkout in your individual machine and commit your changes.

Comment: Indeed as it has been said on the previous command, think about using a Git or SVN repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Solution can be from what i understood you problem is you want both of you should work on same App and even can do your work individual and test it.

Solution can be: 
Suppose you have Login Activity & he has DataViewpage activity. Both work on same project just

Add this in the manifest file in both Activity Login and dataview

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

So This will make 2 icons and both of you can work on same code base and also can test individual pages also..

And Put your code base in github.. so can work from anywhere..

Hope this will help you